# Plotting Octave Plots in RMarkdown

Tags: plot, octave, r-markdown

I am trying to knit Octave code in Rmarkdown , it works fine for printing and text based output , but not knitting the plots to html.

````
```{octave,engine.path='/usr/local/bin/octave/',results='asis',echo= TRUE}
x = -10:0.1:10; # Create an evenly-spaced vector from -10..10
y = sin (x);    # y is also a vector
plot (x, y);
title ("Simple 2-D Plot");
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("sin (x)");
```
````

The parameters `results='asis' ,echo = TRUE` were used as this worked for plotting python plots in html(via Rmarkdown).Has any body been successful in this?

Comment: not an answer, but it might interest you to know Octave has publishing facilities of its own via the `publish` function

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou , thanks , `publish` is a nice way to build a reproducible analysis document. 
One of the reasons I was trying RMarkdown was to compare similar analysis in R,Python and Octave. I tried including the whole html generated from `publish` into the `*.Rmd` but rendering images was again a problem due to dynamic file locations. 
I could however fix it this way (looking for better solutions).
    ```{octave , engine.path = '/usr/local/bin/octave/', results='asis'}
    clf ();
    surf (peaks);
    print -djpg figure2.jpg
    ```
    ![Caption for the picture.](figure2.jpg)