# Rstudio runs Octave via console or REPL

Tags: rstudio, octave

In Rstudio (editor), we can write many codes such as **r**, **python**, **julia**, etc. In particular, we can run the codes line by line directly for **r**, and for **python** and **julia** via `reticulate::repl_python()` and `JuliaCall::julia_console()` respetively. How can we do that for **octave**? BTW, I have already know how to run octave in rmarkdown chunks through [RMarkdown Octave Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512367/rmarkdown-octave-plot) or [Plotting Octave Plots in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578440/plotting-octave-plots-in-rmarkdown), but I want to directly write the octave code in `Rstudio editor` and then test the codes line by line with sending them to octave console or REPL...